# How can I redirect to a website on a remote server using server side code in an MVC web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I am trying to create an ASP.NET MVC web application which connects to a certain website, which I will call website1, on a certain server, which I will call server A, and from this server the user is able to connect to another website, which I will call website2, on a different server, which I will call server B. Server B and any website therein is only accessible from Server A so the redirect from website1 to website2 must be done using server side code. The user needs to be able to initiate the connection to website2 using something similar to a button or a hyperlink.

I am aware that code within a code block of a view which is denoted by @ does run on the server side, but I cannot get code like this to be called in response to user interaction.The `OnClick()` handler for the `<a></a>` tag does not let me call a helper method of the view which might run on the server and neither does `@Html.ActionLink()`. I can call a method of the controller using `@Html.ActionLink("caption","method name")` though I cannot figure out how to write server side code here which will connect me to website2. `Server.Transfer` does not work because this only works for redirecting to pages on the same server. `Response.Redirect` is also out because this uses the client's browser through which server B and website2 would not be accessible.

I would greatly appreciate any direction on resolving this matter as I do not quite know where to go from here. I have been doing searches extensively but have seen nothing which seems to fit with my situation. Please let me know if I have missed anything and I will gladly check it out.

Comment: I found a way to write server side code in the view (denoted by @) which is executed based on a `ViewBag` flag property which I set in the controller method called from `@Html.ActionLink()`. Within the 'If' block checking for the flag being true I have attempted to open website2 using `Response.Redirect` and `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` the former is still using the clients browser while the latter does nothing at all on the server machine in use

Answer (score 0):

You can use this anywhere in your controller:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.anyserveryoulike.org");
```

For example, in the action you reach with your:

```
@Html.ActionLink("caption","method name")
```

Comment: It was my understanding that Response.Redirect() used the client machine's browser which will not work as only the server machine (Server A above) is able to access the target url in this case.

Comment: I went ahead and tried using Response.Redirect in website1 on serverA and I can confirm that it does not work presumably because it is using the client's browser.